# Given a function has second derivative,find the unknown constant a.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

[image]

I have done questions which asks to find unknown constants given the function is continuous. But, this question provides the existence of second derivative at x=1. What information should I draw from it? I would like hints rather than complete answers so that I can try it out myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hints*:

$f$ is continuous at $x=1$ if the value of $x^3$ at $x=1$ equals the value of $ax^2+bx+c$ at $x=1$ (Why?)

$f$ is differentiable at $x=1$ if the value of the derivative of $x^3$ at $x=1$ (i.e., the value of $3x^2$ at $x=1$) equals the value of the derivative of $ax^2+bx+c$ at $x=1$ (Why?)

So, $f$ is twice differentiable at $x=1$ if ...

I hope this helps! Let me know if you require further hints and I'm always happy to assist!

Comment: I got the answer as a=3.

Comment: Yes, @RajathKrishnaR, I agree that's the value of $a$. Note also that twice differentiability of $f$ also implies differentiability of $f$ *and* continuity of $f$. So, in fact, you can also determine the values of $b$ and $c$ in addition to the value of $a$ if you know that $f$ is twice differentiable at $x=1$! (It's useful to remember this and you might like to figure out on your own the values of $b$ and $c$. The process is exactly the same. It's interesting because you need the value of $a$ to determine the value of $b$ and you need the values of $a$ and $b$ to determine the value of $c$.)